# Percentage calculation: What's the difference between using 1.08875 and 0.08875?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Use case is for tax calculation.

Tax is at 8.875%. Using $100 tax-inclusive amount, I get different tax amounts using these formulas:

First:
$$\mathrm{taxAmount} = \$100\times 0.08875 = \$8.875$$
Second:
$$\mathrm{taxAmount} = \$100 - (\frac{\$100}{1.08875}) = \$8.15$$

I find the first formula is the correct one and straightforward but a colleague suggests to use the second.

What's the difference and which one is correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first formula is what you should use if $\$100$ is the price *before* tax, and you are calculating how much tax you need to add on. Thus you have prices of $\$100$ (net) and $\$108.875$ (gross, i.e. net plus tax).

The second formula is what you should use if $\$100$ is the price *after* tax, and you want to work out how much of this was tax. So here you have prices of $\$100$ (gross) and $\$91.85$ (net, i.e. gross minus tax).

As a check, if you apply the first formula to a net price of $\$91.85$ you should get back to $\$100$ gross (there is a small error because the $\$8.15$ in your post is rounded to the nearest cent).

Comment: Following an edit to OP, it is now clear that the second formula is the one you need.

Comment: Yes, the $100 price is tax-inclusive. I kept thinking these 2 formulas should yield the same amount---I was wrong. Thanks for the quick answer!